# How to import mapping parameter in Symfony 2 configuration file?

Tags: symfony, parameters, yaml, configuration-files

Here is what I would expect to work fine:

- parameters.yml

  ```
  host:
      main: example.com
  ```
- app/config/config.yml

  ```
  twig:
      globals:
          hosts_main:   %host.main%
  ```

But an exception is thrown:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]  
 You have requested a non-existent parameter "host.main".
```

And I cannot find any examples in docs.
Strange.
For example, Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters() replaces "flow" notation with mapping if there is one in .dist file and both structures are equal in terms of YAML but Symfony itself seems to not understand YAML.

Could anyone please suggest some adequate workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The parametes key is missing and it should be flat:

```
parameters:
    host.main: example.com
```

Or

```
parameters:
    hosts:
        main: example.com
        other: example.com

twig:
    globals:
        hosts: "%hosts%"
```

Comment: "parameters:" is there. I just didn't paste entire file.

Comment: and I don't need it flat. dot symbol means property access in Twig and I'd like to import parameters into Twig without much transformation. That's another story. But basically I think YAML should remain YAML and not some pidgin.

Comment: Why do you need host.main anyway? It's the host from the request? You can use app.request.host in twig and there is a router.request_context.host parameter if you want to set in the console [see](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html#configuring-the-request-context-globally).

Comment: var name does not matter. I have dozens of them.